# numpy array dimension mismatch error

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append, text-files

I am quite new to numpy and python in general. I am getting a dimension mismatch error when I try to append values even though I have made sure that both arrays have the same dimension. Also another question I have is why does numpy create a single dimensional array when reading in data from a tab delimited text file.

```
import numpy as np

names = ["Angle", "RX_Power", "Frequency"]
data = np.array([0,0,0],float)  #experimental

data = np.genfromtxt("rx_power_mode 0.txt", dtype=float, delimiter='\t', names = names, usecols=[0,1,2], skip_header=1)

freq_177 = np.zeros(shape=(data.shape))

print(freq_177.shape)  #outputs(315,)

for i in range(len(data)):

    if data[i][2] == 177:
        #np.concatenate(freq_177,data[i]) has same issue
        np.append(freq_177,data[i],0)
```

The output I am getting is

> all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

Comment: Can you output the shape of your data? If your data is the same shape as freq_177 you shouldn't be able to index a second dimension

Comment: the data shape is (315,)                                  
data[i] is (0.0, -86.0, 177.0) at i = 0

Comment: I think this happens due to getfromtxt as I try to declare data as multidimentional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotated code:

```
import numpy as np

names = ["Angle", "RX_Power", "Frequency"]
```

You don't need to 'initialize' an array - unless you are going to assign values to individual elements.

```
data = np.array([0,0,0],float)  #experimental
```

This `data` assignment completely overwrites the previous one.

```
data = np.genfromtxt("rx_power_mode 0.txt", dtype=float, delimiter='\t', names = names, usecols=[0,1,2], skip_header=1)
```

Look at `data` at this point.  What is `data.shape`?  What is `data.dtype`?  Print it, or at least some elements.  With `names` I'm guessing that this is a 1d array, with a 3 field `dtype`.  It's not a 2d array, though, with all floats it could transformed/view as such.

Why are you making a 1d array of zeros?

```
freq_177 = np.zeros(shape=(data.shape))
print(freq_177.shape)  #outputs(315,)
```

With a structured array like `data`, the preferred way to index a given element is by field name and row number, eg.  data['frequency'][i]`. Play with that.

`np.append` is not the same as the list append.  It returns a value; it does not change `freq_177` in place.  Same for `concatenate`.  I recommend staying away from `np.append`.  It's too easy to use it in the wrong way and place.

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    if data[i][2] == 177:
        #np.concatenate(freq_177,data[i]) has same issue
        np.append(freq_177,data[i],0)
```

It looks like you want to collect in `freq_177` all the terms of the `data` array for which the 'frequency' field is 177.

```
I = data['frequency'].astype(int)==177
freq_177 = data[I]
```

I have used `astype(int)` because the `==` test with floats is uncertain.  It is best used with integers.

`I` is a boolean mask, true where the values match; `data[I]` then is the corresponding elements of `data`.  The `dtype` will match that of `data`, that is, it will have 3 fields.  You can't append or concatenate it to an array of float zeros (your original `freq_177`).

If you must iterate and collect values, I suggest using list append, e.g.

```
alist = []
for row in data:
   if int(row['frequency'])==177:
       alist.append(row)
freq177 = np.array(alist)
```

---

I don't think `np.append` is discussed much except in its own `doc` page and text.  It comes up periodically in SO questions.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.append.html

> Returns:  append : ndarray
>
> A copy of arr with values appended to axis. Note that append does not occur in-place: a new array is allocated and filled.

See also `help(np.append)` in an interpreter shell.

For `genfromtxt` - it too has docs, and lots of SO discussion.  But to understand what it returned in this case, you need to also read about `structured arrays` and `compound dtype`.  (add links?)

Try loading the data with:

```
data = np.genfromtxt("rx_power_mode 0.txt", dtype=float, delimiter='\t', usecols=[0,1,2], skip_header=1)
```

Since you are skipping the header line, and just using columns with floats, `data` should be a 2d array with 3 columns, `(N, 3)`.  In that case you could access the 'frequency' values with `data[:,2]`

```
I = int(data[:,2])==177
freq_177 = data[I,:]
```

`freq_177` is now be a 3 column array - with a subset of the `data` rows.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. That worked really well. I had a few more questions. First i m not sure why does genfromtxt return a 1d array. Second could you point out to a good reference for numpy. I was looking at Scipy.org for function append but all it says is that it appends values to the end of an array. Could have never figured out this solution on my own.

Comment: I added some notes on documentation.  I should also have suggested how you could load your data so it produces a 2d array (assuming it's all numbers).

Comment: Ahhh now I understand how you created a boolean array and filtered out the results. So after going through the documentation for genfromtxt I see that it returns an nd array. But the weird thing is even loadtxt returns an ndarray. But if I use loadtxt on my example file(as I have no missing values for now) it does end up returning a 2d array. Maybe it has to do with the way it processes data.  In any case your additional comments were super helpful. Thanks a lot.